# Random number generator in c#

Tags: c#

I need two function.one will generate random even numbers and 2nd will generate random odd numbers.Is there any in-built function in c#?

Thanks

Comment: Generate a number if odd add in oddlist and if even add in evenlist.

Comment: Did maked some research before asking question?
`Random` class it's what you asking for

Comment: @Amrit Why don't you write one yourself?

Comment: Generate a random number with the `Random` class, return such a number times 2 to get an even number and such a number times 2 plus 1 to get an odd number ...

Comment: Do you need a true or rather close to true random number? If your answer is yes, then answer to your question is no.

Comment: Take it easy brothers, we have here a learner...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like that:

```
private static int RandomNumberEven(int min, int max)
        {
            Random random = new Random();
            int ans = random.Next(min, max);
            if (ans % 2 == 0) return ans;
            else
            {
                if (ans + 1 <= max)
                    return ans + 1;
                else if (ans - 1 >= min)
                    return ans - 1;
                else return 0;
            }
        }

private static int RandomNumberOdd(int min, int max)
        {
            Random random = new Random();
            int ans = random.Next(min, max);
            if (ans % 2 == 1) return ans;
            else
            {
                if (ans + 1 <= max)
                    return ans + 1;
                else if (ans - 1 >= min)
                    return ans - 1;
                else return 0;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 9):

If you don't have any special requirement about the distribuition you can use the regular random C# function:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
            rnd.Next(int.MaxValue/2)*2; // an even integer
            rnd.Next(int.MaxValue/2)*2+1; // an odd integer
```

**NOTE**
You probably would adjust the min/max range accordingly to avoid overflows and to stay in your range.

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal if you are asking for an odd/even number you are already leaking randomness: but you need to invoke one time for the even and one time for the odd so the two are not related :)

Comment: This code could cause overflow and result in a negative number. You need either checking for overflow or limiting it like this : rnd.Next(int.MaxValue / 2);

Comment: @TomasGrosup yep you are corrent, it is sated in the comment, but I modified the code to work anyway.

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal It's not an even number that is being doubled, just an integer. And as all odds can be expressed as `2n+1` where `n` is integer, the solution is not missing any or favoring any.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

(I have assumed that you need 10 odd and 10 even numbers)

```
Random r = new Random();

List<int> even = new List<int>();
List<int> odd = new List<int>();

while(even.Count < 10 || odd.Count < 10)
{
    int i = r.Next();
    if(i % 2 == 0)
    {
        if(!even.Contains(i) && even.Count < 10)
            even.Add(i);
    }
    else
    {
        if(!odd.Contains(i) && odd.Count < 10)
            odd.Add(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: your code is looking for *unique* evens/odds numbers that is not stated in the OP. If the amount of number requested is >>10 *Contains* will increase too much the complexity.